# Bootstrap grid system layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I have a question about formatting using bootstrap's grid system...
I would like to achieve an effect like the images below, but the only way I can seem to do it is to repeat the layout using `visible-xs` and `hidden-xs`. Is it possible to do this using only bootstrap's grid system?

**Mobile Layout**

[image]

---

**Desktop Layout**

[image]

My code so far looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
<h1>My Schedules</h1>
<br>
<div class="visible-xs">
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Trimester 1</button>
        <br><br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Trimester 2</button>
        <br><br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Trimester 3</button>
        <br><br>
    </div>


</div>

<div class="hidden-xs col-sm-2">
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Trimester 1</button>
        <br><br>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Trimester 2</button>
        <br><br>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Trimester 3</button>
        <br><br>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs" style="background-color:gray; height:50%;"></div>
<div class="col-sm-10 hidden-xs" style="background-color:gray; height:50%;"></div>

</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use rows, http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html. Wrap whatever you want in <div class='row'></div>, as shown in grid section in the doco, then internally size using col-offset if needed. Posting answer but no time to mockup using your code sorry (started fiddle but took too long), but very easy to see from examples on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this (I haven't tested it, but you get the idea):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Trimester 1</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Trimester 2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Trimester 3</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <!-- Here you put the grey rectangle -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way, your three trimester buttons would appear all in the same row in smaller devices, with the grey rectangle in another row.

Comment: Thank you, the nested rows and columns were confusing me, but this cleared it up!

Comment: I feel you, I've struggled with that a few times. It was my pleasure to be able to help ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Use rows, http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Wrap whatever you want in , as shown in grid section in the doco, then internally size using col-offset if needed

Example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
</div>
```

Each row has 12 spans, and you can offset too (see link)

*EDIT*

pasted bootstrap2 css by mistake, updated to BS3

Answer (score 0):

Working setup.

```css
.headImg,
.bodyImg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
h1 {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.btn-primary {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.vertical-btn {
  text-align: center;
}
.btn-group {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .vertical-btn .btn-group .btn {
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline;
  }
  h1 {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .vertical-btn .btn-group .btn {
    margin: 10px 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/1850x250/444/fff" class="headImg">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <h1>My Schedules</h1>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="vertical-btn">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Trimester 1</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Trimester 2</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Trimester 3</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/850x250/444/fff" class="bodyImg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```